# What is the integration contour used to compute the Fourier transform of $(1- e^{-x})^{-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm reading "Modular Groups of Quantum Fields
in Thermal States" by Borchers and Yngvason, and on page 19 I find:

[image]

Let's call $x=\beta p \in \mathbb{R}$, so I'm interested in the Fourier transform of $(1-e^{-x})^{-1}$.

I have tried a contour that avoids the origin with a small arc (in the upper-half plane)  and closing with a large arc also in the upper half-plane, but the contribution from the small arc does not vanish, and this contour would also have infinite contributions from the residues at $2 \pi i n$, with $n$ a positive integer. I have also tried with a rectangular contour, of width $2L$ and height $2\pi$, with its lower horizontal segment an $\epsilon$ distance below the real axis (so to avoid the pole at the origin). The integrals along the horizontal segments can be related, and the integral along the left vertical segment goes to zero for $L\rightarrow \infty$, but the right vertical segment still contributes to the contour integral.

So, any suggestions on other possible contours?

Comment: I suspect that some sort of "principal value integration" near $0$ is necessary to make rigorous sense of this (not to mention that even ignoring stuff near $0$, the function is not in $L^2$ nor $L^1$, so, again, something distributional is necessary...)

Comment: I agree! But the paper was so "cool" about it, that I thought may be it was more or less easy to pinpoint the correct contour of integration. I will try to make sense of it as a distribution. And I'll keep an eye here in case someone suggests something else.

Comment: @paulgarrett A precise statement is that, with their definition of the Fourier transform,
$$\mathcal F {\left[ x \mapsto \frac 1 {1 - e^{-x + i0}} \right]}(\xi) =
\frac i {1 - e^{2 \pi \xi - i0}},$$
where $f(x \pm i0)$ are the distributional limits, $(1 - e^{-x + i0})^{-1}$ is not equal to the p.v. distribution $\mathcal P((1 - e^{-x})^{-1})$.

Comment: @Maxim would you elaborate on that? May be as an answer? I'm interested in understanding how you are taking the fourier transform of that distribution.

Comment: @Maxim, if so, then actually it _is_ the principal value integral, plus an extra term, essentially as in the Sokhotski-Plemelj formula, I think. No necessity to use that fact, I guess, except that it does connect to other things, perhaps usefully.

Comment: $(1 - e^{-x + i0})^{-1}$ is the distributional derivative of $f(x) = \ln(1 - e^x)$, where $\ln$ is the principal branch. We can first find the FT of the regular distribution $f(x) - g(x)$ with $g(x) = (x + \pi i) H(x)$:
$$\mathcal F[f - g](\xi) =
\frac {1 - \pi \xi \coth \pi \xi} {2 \pi \xi^2}$$
and then show that $i \xi (\mathcal F[f - g](\xi) + \mathcal F[g](\xi)) = i (1 - e^{2 \pi \xi - i0})^{-1}$, but that's probably not the easiest way.

Comment: @paulgarrett Correct, $(1 - e^{-x + i0})^{-1} = \mathcal P((1 - e^{-x})^{-1}) + \pi i \delta(x)$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the details. But I'm missing what you gain by substracting $g(x)$, in particular the linear term (the other one I think cancels out the $i \pi$ from the negative argument in $ln$). Because of this I'm not being able to reproduce $\mathcal{F}[f-g]$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @Maxim. 
Also, if I use your answer to paulgarret in terms of the principal value, or if I perform a countour integral closing with a large arc in the upper-half plane (for $\xi>0$, or lowe-half plane for $\xi<0$),  I end up with: 
$$ \mathcal{F}[(1-e^{-x+i0})^{-1}](\xi) = 2\pi i \frac{\text{sgn}(\xi)}{1-e^{-2\pi \xi}}$$
Not sure if I'm missing a delta-like contribution at $\xi=0$

Comment: $f - g$ is a regular distribution corresponding to an $L^1(\mathbb R)$ function, so its distributional FT is the regular distribution corresponding to $(2 \pi)^{-1} \int_{\mathbb R} (f(x) - g(x)) e^{-i \xi x} dx$, in other words, we reduce computing the FT to operations on ordinary functions. $\operatorname {sgn}(\xi)(1 - e^{-2 \pi \xi})^{-1}$ doesn't define a regular distribution, so you have to specify what that notation means, that is, how $(\operatorname {sgn}(\xi)(1 - e^{-2 \pi \xi})^{-1}, \phi(\xi))$  is computed for a test function $\phi$.

Comment: @Maxim, right, I should have clarified I meant principal value, since it is only valid for $\xi\neq0$. Actually, what I wrote has a mistake and the sign function should not appear, and I realize I'm using a different convention for the Fourier transform (you are using the one of the paper that motivated my question, so my bad). 
I now understand how to compute the FT by direct contour integration. I will write it as an answer in full detail.